# Angular nested SVG component is invisible

Tags: angular, svg

I'm using two SVG components as described [here](https://angular.io/guide/svg-in-templates). Now I want to use one component inside the other. But when I do this the nested component is invisible. There is no error and with the debugger tool, I can see the component being rendered inside the SVG but with a width and height of 0.

How can I change the dimensions of the component?

I tried doing something like this: `<app-text-svg width="200"></app-text-svg>` but it doesn't work because it has no width attribute.

My full code:

```
text-svg.component.ts:

@Component({
  selector: 'app-text-svg',
  templateUrl: './text-svg.component.svg',
  styleUrls: ['text-svg.component.scss']
})
export class TextSvgComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() text: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```

```
text-svg.component.svg:


<svg width="320" height="160" viewBox="0 0 320 160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    .text { font: 26px sans-serif; }
  </style>

  <text x="160" y="80" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" class="text">{{text}}</text>
</svg>
```

```
main-svg.component.svg:


<svg width="800" height="600" viewBox="0 0 800 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <app-text-svg [text]="'test'"></text-svg>
</svg>
```

[stackblitz](https://angular-ivy-n6o8ml.stackblitz.io)

This is a simplified example. I know that this wouldn't make much sense if this would be all my code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component `app-text-svg` is a custom (non-SVG) Web Component and those components unfortunately can't be displayed inside an SVG, unless through the help of foreignObjects(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject).

If you want to directly include your component as SVG you could extend the base text-node with a different selector, your text-component could then e.g. look like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'text[appTextSvg]',
  template: `
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      :host {
        font: 26px sans-serif;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class TextSvgComponent {
  @HostBinding('attr.x') x = 160;
  @HostBinding('attr.y') y = 80;
  @HostBinding('attr.dominantBaseline') dominantBaseline = 'middle';
  @HostBinding('attr.textAnchor') textAnchor = 'middle';
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ypx3ku?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Extra Info: If you want to handle the text through an Input you can of course do that as well, imo the use of ng-content here is more fitting though.

Answer (score -4):

Why load a **143 Kb** Angular Framework, if you can do it with **3** lines of Vanilla JavaScript:

Display centered text with svg with the smallest Web Component <svg-text>

```html
<style>
  svg {
    background: pink;
    width: 120px
  }
</style>

<svg-text>Hello</svg-text>
<svg-text>Web</svg-text>
<svg-text>Components</svg-text>
<svg-text>Bye Bye</svg-text>
<svg-text>Frameworks</svg-text>

<script>
  customElements.define("svg-text", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => this.replaceWith(Object.assign(document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg"), { innerHTML: `<style>.text { font:21px sans-serif}</style><text x="50%" y="50%" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" class="text">${this.innerHTML}</text>`})))}})
</script>
```